# duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run the following query in MySQL,

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO shop_item_details (shop_id,product_id,product_name,Product_model,Product_category,Product_details,price) 
 VALUES (1, NULL, 'camera', 'sony','', 'hd', '5000') 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY 
 UPDATE (shop_id='1',product_id='',product_name='camera', Product_model='sony',Product_category='', Product_details='hd',price='5000')
```

But it shows the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
>   syntax to use near '(shop_id='1',product_id='',product_name='camera', 
>   Product_model='sony',Product_c' at line 1

What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 3):

**This good one:**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO shop_item_details (shop_id,product_id,product_name,Product_model,Product_category,Product_details,price) 
 VALUES (1, NULL, 'camera', 'sony','', 'hd', '5000') 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE shop_id='1',product_id='',product_name='camera', Product_model='sony',Product_category='', Product_details='hd',price='5000';
```

remove brackets around update

Answer (score 0):

you just need to remove the brakets around update

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE shop_id='1' ,product_id='', product_name='camera', Product_model='sony', Product_category='', Product_details='hd', price='5000';
```